# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

Here's the code:

```
getUsersObservable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    //.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map { user: User ->
        user.email = String.format("%s@rxjava.wtf", user.name)
        user.name = user.name!!.toUpperCase()
    }
    .subscribe(object : Observer<User> {
        override fun onComplete() {
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        }

        override fun onNext(t: User) {
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        }
    })
```

I get the following error:

> /Users/johann/Work/Dev/Kotlin/rxjava-walkthrough-kotlin/app/src/test/java/ktplay/RxKotlinPlay.kt:
>   (49, 14): None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied: @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final
>   fun subscribe(p0: ((Unit) -> Unit)!): Disposable! defined in
>   io.reactivex.Observable @SchedulerSupport public final fun
>   subscribe(p0: Observer): Unit defined in
>   io.reactivex.Observable @CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public
>   final fun subscribe(p0: Consumer!): Disposable! defined in
>   io.reactivex.Observable

This error occurs on the line with subscribe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, your `map` operator takes a `User` and returns a `Unit` instead of `User`. It should look like this instead:

```
.map { user: User ->
    user.email = String.format("%s@rxjava.wtf", user.name)
    user.name = user.name!!.toUpperCase()
    user
}
```

Comment: I was really close. I put the word "return" in front of the last line but it complained that "return is not allowed here". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's an article that covers the return statement on lambdas: https://medium.com/@belokon.roman/return-from-kotlins-lambda-411171923756

Comment: I'm not very well versed in RxJava, but I think [doOnNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#doOnNext-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-) would be more appropriate than `map` if the goal is just to perform mutations on each object

Answer (score 1):

Only modify into Subscribe "safe" **Observer(User?>**

```
    .subscribe(object: Observer<User?> {
                override fun onNext(t: User) {
                    // Perform the value of `t`
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    // Perform something on complete
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    // Disposable provided
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    // Handling error
                }
            })
```

Comment: absolutely correct!